# Extract choice number with regex from a string in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I have a string like this:

```
string S = "\nHello and welcom choose one\n response\r\n1:response1\r\n2:choice number 2\r\n3:The Third choice\nin the list\r\n4:You can choose the last response.\n";
```

It can change the number of responses and the text formatting, but it always has the format `(1:response .... number:response)`.

I want to make a function with regular expressions which selects the response.

In this example, I want to return the number which contains the word "last" (4) and return 0 if the response wasn't found:

```
int r1 = SomeFunction (S, "last");
int r2 = SomeFunction (S, "bla bla");
Console.Writeline("r1 ---> {0}", r1); // should display r1 ---> 4
Console.Writeline("r2 ---> {0}", r2); // should display r2 ---> 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different way of doing it (mix of reading the lines and regex-ing each line):

```
static int FindOption(string options, string name)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(options))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null) break;
            Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"^\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*(.*)");
            if (match.Success && match.Groups[2].Value.Contains(name))
            {
                return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If your text is too long it is possibly better to do it this way. By the way, this regex is made a little tolerant (notice white spaces `\s*`). If your text more rigid you might not event need a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that Regexes are the most practical approach to solving this problem (you could use an array). However, here you go:

Basically, you create a `pattern` that will look for any one-digit number, followed by any text, followed by the word you want (e.g. "last"). Then you **capture** that number (using the parenthesis in the variable `pattern`). And you return it using `match.Groups[1]`.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string S = "\nHello and welcom choose one\n response\r\n1:response1\r\n2:choice number 2\r\n3:The Third choice\nin the list\r\n4:You can choose the last response.\n";
        Console.WriteLine(GetNumber (S, "last"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetNumber (S, "bla bla"));
    }

    private static string GetNumber(string inputText, string match)
    {
        string pattern = @".*(\d):.*?" + match;
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);

        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(inputText))
        {
          if (myMatch.Success)
          {
             return myMatch.Groups[1].Value;
          }
        }

        return "0";
    }
}
```

But, I repeat: you don't look like you know the basics of C# yet, so already diving into Regexes doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: No the prob is that the string S is dynamique and i want to catch the choice when s change ! S is not the same every time !

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d)(?=[^\d]*?last)
```

You can try this.Employes a positive lookahaead for word "last".

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/4